# Send email when account or opportunity records are shared manually

Tags: email, opportunity, account, sharing, manual-sharing

There is a requirement where if an account or opportunity record is shared manually with a user, the user should get an email.
Seems like there is no way to create a trigger on share objects. Does anyone know how can we achieve this usecase?

I can use some scheduled job to check for the new account share
OR
I can override the Lightning button for sharing, but for this, I have to build the UI, which I don't want to.

Comment: there's an [Idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdkJwUAJ/notify-user-checkbox-on-manual-record-sharing?sfdcIFrameOrigin=null) for this

Comment: @cropredy I have seen that post, but that's not what I want

Comment: Scheduled Apex or button override are probably the only ways to do it.